# How can I highlight text before a character with listing?

Tags: listings, highlighting, makefile

All is in the title. I would like to add a color to the text before a character with listing package.

For example, I would like to add a color to text between the beginning of a line and `:` or `=`, in a makefile.

I tried to use `moredelimiters` but I did not succeed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{keycolor}{RGB}{172, 42, 42}
\definecolor{mbleu}{RGB}{64,96,127}
\definecolor{vimvert}{RGB}{46, 139, 87}

\lstdefinestyle{global}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color{black!90},%
  stringstyle=\itshape\color{magenta},%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{keycolor}},%
  commentstyle=\color{blue}\slshape,%
  framexleftmargin=1mm,%
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!2},%
}

\lstdefinestyle{makefile}{
  style=global,%
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{\#},%
  emphstyle={\color{vimvert}},%
  moredelim=[s][emphstyle]{\$(}{)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=makefile]
.SUFFIXES: .inc .f .f90 .F

# all CPP processed fortran files have the extension .f90
SUFFIX=.f90

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# this release should be fpp clean
# we now recommend fpp as preprocessor
# if this fails go back to cpp
CPP_=fpp -f_com=no -free -w0 $*.F $*$(SUFFIX)

vasp: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(INC) main.o 
    rm -f vasp
    $(FCL) -o vasp main.o  $(SOURCE)   $(FFT3D) $(LIB) $(LINK)
makeparam: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makeparam.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o makeparam  $(LINK) makeparam.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
zgemmtest: zgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o zgemmtest $(LINK) zgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB)
dgemmtest: dgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o dgemmtest $(LINK) dgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB) 
ffttest: base.o smart_allocate.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o ffttest.o $(FFT3D) $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o ffttest $(LINK) ffttest.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o smart_allocate.o base.o $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
kpoints: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makekpoints.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o kpoints $(LINK) makekpoints.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)

clean:  
    -rm -f *.g *.f *.o *.L *.mod ; touch *.F
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a MWE, so that we have a basis for experimenting?

Comment: I add a short example. Actually, at then end I would like the code to look like vim syntax coloring.

Comment: @hpesoj626: I think your comment is the most common solution. Can you provide an answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found recently an alternative using the `minted` package with `pygmentize`. The inconvenient is that it is not a fully LaTeX solution.

[image: minted package]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{make}
.SUFFIXES: .inc .f .f90 .F

# all CPP processed fortran files have the extension .f90
SUFFIX=.f90

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# this release should be fpp clean
# we now recommend fpp as preprocessor
# if this fails go back to cpp
CPP_=fpp -f_com=no -free -w0 $*.F $*$(SUFFIX)

vasp: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(INC) main.o 
    rm -f vasp
    $(FCL) -o vasp main.o  $(SOURCE)   $(FFT3D) $(LIB) $(LINK)
makeparam: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makeparam.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o makeparam  $(LINK) makeparam.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
zgemmtest: zgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o zgemmtest $(LINK) zgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB)
dgemmtest: dgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o dgemmtest $(LINK) dgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB) 
ffttest: base.o smart_allocate.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o ffttest.o $(FFT3D) $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o ffttest $(LINK) ffttest.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o smart_allocate.o base.o $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
kpoints: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makekpoints.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o kpoints $(LINK) makekpoints.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)

clean:  
    rm -f *.g *.f *.o *.L *.mod ; touch *.F
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can externally process files with `pymentize` and then include the output using `fancyvrb`. This way you can circumvent the `shell-escape`.

Answer (score 7):

`.SUFFIXES` is a keyword in the pre-defined language `[gnu]make`. `SUFFIX` is pre-defined in `ACSL` but loading the languages through a combination of `language` and `alsolanguage` and `classoffset` keys don't seem to give the desired effect. I suggest that you define your `makefile` as in the following work-arounds.

## Work-around 1

In this solution, the colon, `:` is also colored. Just set up your `\lstdefinestyle` as follows:

```
\lstdefinestyle{global}{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color{black!90},%
stringstyle=\itshape\color{magenta},%
showstringspaces=false,%
keywordstyle={[1]\bfseries\color{keycolor}},%
keywordstyle={[2]\bfseries\color{mbleu}},%
commentstyle=\color{blue}\slshape,%
framexleftmargin=1mm,%
backgroundcolor=\color{black!2},%
}

\lstdefinestyle{makefile}{
otherkeywords={.SUFFIXES},
alsoletter={:},
morekeywords=[1]{SUFFIX, CPP_},
morekeywords=[2]{vasp:,makeparam:,zgemmtest:,dgemmtest:,ffttest:,kpoints:,clean:},
style=global,%
morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{\#},%
emphstyle={\color{vimvert}},%
moredelim=[s][\color{vimvert}]{\$(}{)}%
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Explanations

- `otherkeywords` defines keywords that contain other characters, *or start with digits*.
- `alsoletter` makes `:` a letter, otherwise, words containing these symbols will not be recognized as words.
- You can make separate lists of `morekeywords` or `moreemph` by the syntax `morekeywords=[<number>]{<list of keywords>}` or `moreemph=[<number>]{<list of emphs>}`. Here I have chosen `keywords` but you can modify according to your preference. You have then to match this list with a corresponding `keywordstyle` or `emphstyle`.

## Work-around 2

You might not want the colon colored. In this case, you can use (guess what?) `moredelim` as in `moredelim=[is][\color{mbleu}]{/*}{*/},` From the manual:

> More general delimiters can be defined by the key moredelim. Legal types are `l` and `s`. These types can be preceded by an `i`, but this time only the delimiters are discarded from the output.

And here is the full code

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{keycolor}{RGB}{172, 42, 42}
\definecolor{mbleu}{RGB}{64,96,127}
\definecolor{vimvert}{RGB}{46, 139, 87}

\lstdefinestyle{global}{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color{black!90},%
stringstyle=\itshape\color{magenta},%
showstringspaces=false,%
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keycolor},%
commentstyle=\color{blue}\slshape,%
framexleftmargin=1mm,%
backgroundcolor=\color{black!2},%
    }

\lstdefinestyle{makefile}{
otherkeywords={.SUFFIXES},
morekeywords={SUFFIX, CPP_,},
moredelim=[is][\color{mbleu}]{/*}{*/},
style=global,%
morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{\#},%
emphstyle={\color{vimvert}},%
moredelim=[s][\color{vimvert}]{\$(}{)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=makefile]
.SUFFIXES: .inc .f .f90 .F

# all CPP processed fortran files have the extension .f90
SUFFIX=.f90

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# this release should be fpp clean
# we now recommend fpp as preprocessor
# if this fails go back to cpp
CPP_=fpp -f_com=no -free -w0 $*.F $*$(SUFFIX)

/*vasp*/: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(INC) main.o 
        rm -f vasp
        $(FCL) -o vasp main.o  $(SOURCE)   $(FFT3D) $(LIB) $(LINK)
/*makeparam*/: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makeparam.o main.F $(INC)
        $(FCL) -o makeparam  $(LINK) makeparam.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
/*zgemmtest*/: zgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
        $(FCL) -o zgemmtest $(LINK) zgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB)
/*dgemmtest*/: dgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
        $(FCL) -o dgemmtest $(LINK) dgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB) 
/*ffttest*/: base.o smart_allocate.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o ffttest.o $(FFT3D) $(INC)
        $(FCL) -o ffttest $(LINK) ffttest.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o smart_allocate.o base.o $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
/*kpoints*/: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makekpoints.o main.F $(INC)
        $(FCL) -o kpoints $(LINK) makekpoints.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
/*clean*/:  
        -rm -f *.g *.f *.o *.L *.mod ; touch *.F
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[The answer posted by hpesoj626](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101730/21891) shows two approaches that produce the desired output; they are perfectly acceptable for a small number of lines. Unfortunately, those two approaches quickly become tedious and unmaintainable as the number of targets increase, because they lack automation:

- workaround 1 requires defining all the `make` target names (e.g. `vasp`, `makeparam`, etc.) as keywords;
- workaround 2 requires altering the listing by surrounding all targets names with custom delimiters.

I'm assuming you need an automated solution that requires neither defining a long list of keywords or modifying the original listing. The following assumes that your question is really

> Can I get 'listings' to automatically highlight text before a given character? If so, how?

### Short answer

Yes and no; but mostly no.

### More detailed answer

The `listings` package reads a listing in a pretty much linear fashion. As far as I know, it can't really look ahead very far and then backtrack to apply a style conditionally on what it has found.

In some cases, though, it's possible to mess with `listings`'s internals just enough to get what you want. You can define switches, counters, etc. whose values are updated when a given character or identifier is encountered, or at certain `listings` "hooks". You can then use those "state variables" to conditionally apply styles.

In particular, here, in order to only get `make` targets highlighted in magenta, I set the current style to magenta colour at the beginning of each line (via the hook called `EveryLine` that `listings` provides) and I revert back to the "default" style (black color) as soon as I encounter a colon.

Note that my approach still requires you to define your `make` variables as keywords if you want them highglighted in a different style than the targets; I can't think of a robust way to have variables automatically highlighted in a style different to that of targets. However, I believe that the number of variables in a typical makefile is usually less than the number of targets, so defining each variable as `listings` keyword shouldn't be that much hassle...

### Why are tab characters missing in action?

If you simply copy the code below, paste it in your favourite editor, and compile, you will *not* obtain the same output as that shown on my screenshot. That's because command lines in makefiles are preceded by tabstops, but TeX.SX replaces all tabstops by four spaces. You'll have to reinsert the tabstops in my code manually before compiling; then everything should work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% --- color definitions ---
\definecolor{mktext}    {RGB}{000, 043, 054}
\definecolor{mktarget}  {RGB}{211, 054, 130}
\definecolor{mkstring}  {RGB}{000, 127, 127}
\definecolor{mkvariable}{RGB}{038, 139, 210}
\definecolor{mkkeyword} {RGB}{133, 153, 000}
\definecolor{mklinecont}{RGB}{220, 050, 047}
\definecolor{mkcomment} {RGB}{088, 110, 117}
\definecolor{mkcommand} {RGB}{042, 161, 152}

% --- auxiliary macros for styles ---
\newcommand\mktextstyle{\color{mktext}}
\newcommand\mktargetstyle{\color{mktarget}}
\newcommand\mkstringstyle{\color{mkstring}}
\newcommand\mkvariablestyle{\color{mkvariable}}
\newcommand\mkkeywordstyle{\color{mkkeyword}}
\newcommand\mklinecontstyle{\color{mklinecont}}
\newcommand\mkcommentstyle{\slshape\color{mkcomment}}
\newcommand\mkcommandstyle{\color{mkcommand}}

\makeatletter
% --- context switches ---
\newif\iftarget@make@
\newif\iflinecont@make@

% --- hook into listings to keep track of context ---
\lst@AddToHook{InitVarsBOL}
{%
  \iflinecont@make@%
    \global\target@make@false%
  \else
    \global\target@make@true%
  \fi
  \global\linecont@make@false%
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \iftarget@make@%
        \gdef\globalstyle@make{\the@lststyle}%
        \def\lst@thestyle{\mktargetstyle}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode% only test for keyword if we're in "processing" mode
    \lsthk@DetectKeywords%
  \fi
}

\lstdefinestyle{make-pretty}
{
  upquote=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\mktextstyle,
  sensitive=true,
  alsoletter=.-,
  keywords = {.CC,.CFLAGS,.PHONY,.SUFFIXES,SUFFIX,CPP_},
  keywordstyle = \mkkeywordstyle,
  moredelim=[is][\mkvariablestyle(\aftergroup\closingparen@make]{(}{)},
  moredelim=*[l][\mkcommandstyle]{\^^I},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  stringstyle=\mkstringstyle,
  literate =
    {\%}{{{\mkvariablestyle\%}}}1
    {\$}{{{\mkvariablestyle\$}}}1
    {\$*}{{{\mkvariablestyle\$*}}}2
    {\\}{{{\mklinecontstyle\lstum@backslash}}}1,
  MoreSelectCharTable =
    \processColon@make
    \processEqual@make
    \processBackslash@make
    \processTab@make,
  morecomment = [l]{\#},
  commentstyle = \mkcommentstyle,
}

% --- helper macros ---
\newcommand\closingparen@make{{\mkvariablestyle)}}

\newcommand\processEqual@make
{%
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`=}\equal@make%
  {%
    \equal@make%
    \global\target@make@false%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\globalstyle@make}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\processColon@make
{%
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`:}\colon@make%
  {%
    \colon@make%
    \global\target@make@false%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\globalstyle@make}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\processBackslash@make
{%
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`\\}\backslash@make%
  {%
    \backslash@make%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \global\linecont@make@true%
      \def\lst@thestyle{\globalstyle@make}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\newcommand\processTab@make
{%
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`^^I}\tabchar@make%
  {%
    \tabchar@make%
    \global\target@make@false%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=make-pretty]
.SUFFIXES: .inc .f .f90 .F

# all CPP processed fortran files have the extension .f90
SUFFIX=.f90

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# this release should be fpp clean
# we now recommend fpp as preprocessor
# if this fails go back to cpp
CPP_=fpp -f_com=no -free -w0 $*.F $*$(SUFFIX)

vasp: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(INC) main.o 
    rm -f vasp
    $(FCL) -o vasp main.o  $(SOURCE)   $(FFT3D) $(LIB) $(LINK)
makeparam: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makeparam.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o makeparam  $(LINK) makeparam.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
zgemmtest: zgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o zgemmtest $(LINK) zgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB)
dgemmtest: dgemmtest.o base.o random.o $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o dgemmtest $(LINK) dgemmtest.o random.o base.o $(LIB) 
ffttest: base.o smart_allocate.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o ffttest.o $(FFT3D) $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o ffttest $(LINK) ffttest.o mpi.o mgrid.o random.o smart_allocate.o base.o $(FFT3D) $(LIB)
kpoints: $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) makekpoints.o main.F $(INC)
    $(FCL) -o kpoints $(LINK) makekpoints.o $(SOURCE) $(FFT3D) $(LIB)

clean:  
    rm -f *.g *.f *.o *.L *.mod ; touch *.F
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, you are such a hacker :-)

Comment: @Daniel Nah! I've just been playing around with `listings` internals for one of my packages; so, when I see a question that looks answerable, I jump on it `:p`

Comment: Nice, but it is a little bit hard ...

Comment: @Ger Yes, "a little bit" :) The `listings` package has a lot of nice features, but it doesn't allow for you asked very easily.