# More sophisticated syntax highlighting of Prolog code

Tags: listings, packages, color, highlighting

I'm wondering, does listings allow you to define your own syntax highlighting, and if so, how sophisticated is its system?

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{emph={%  
   {:-}%
     },emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries\underbar}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Prolog]
    foo(Arg1, Arg2) :-
      bar(Arg3),
      baz(Arg4),
      length([1,2,3], 3).
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, in the following code sample, "foo" would be highlighted (since it's declaring a new clause), as would ":-".

I tried to use emph and morekeywords to highlight :-, but neither worked.
They seems to work for regular words like "for" and "while",
but not for the sequence ":-". Is there a special way to escape this to add a keyword?

To highlight the name of the predicate before :-, I have no idea how I would tackle that. It's not essential, but it would be nice if I could get it working. Can I define custom syntax/grammar for highlighting Prolog?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81646/how-can-i-highlight-text-before-a-character-with-listing and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161235/how-do-i-customize-listings-to-mimic-the-highlighting-of-prolog-code-in-minted

Comment: `emph` and `keywords` won't highlight characters such as `:` and `-` because `listings` treats them as "other" characters; you'll have to declare them as "letters" by using `alsoletter=:-,`. As for highlighting stuff before `:-`, see my comment to the question at the end of the second link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a direct answer to your question, but I recommend the rather wonderful package [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/). It uses `pygments` to highlight a wide variety of languages. Keep in mind that you'll need to pass `-shell-escape` to `latex` so that it can call out to `pygments`. Documentation [here (pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf).

Frankly, I switched to minted because setting up anything complex in `listings` quickly got out of hand for my tastes.