# Can the listings package be set up to highlight Prolog code like minted does?

Tags: listings, color, highlighting, minted

I am interested to know how `listings` can be customized to mimic the *Pygments's Prolog lexer* (i.e. make Prolog code represented by `listings` look the same as it is done with `minted`)

I previously asked this question: [How to make a minted code listing centered on a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161124/how-to-make-a-minted-code-listing-centered-on-a-page)

Jubobs commented on that question and encouraged me to post this question.

My previous question was answered by egreg, who provided the following example, and this is exactly how I want my code listing to look like in my report:

[image: mintedListing]

However, I need a lot of extra packages for this solution. So I am wondering if the same (or very similar) result can be achieved by customizing `listings`.

Jubobs already provided the following `lstdefinestyle` example:

```
\lstdefinestyle{myPrologstyle}
{
    language=Prolog,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily\color{blue},
    moredelim = [s][\color{black}]{(}{)},
    literate =
        {:-}{{\textcolor{black}{:-}}}2
        {,}{{\textcolor{black}{,}}}1
        {.}{{\textcolor{black}{.}}}1
}
```

This however is not sufficient enough for me. For example, the variables are not highlighted in the dark blue color as it is done in `minted`.

Here is another (more complete) example of how Prolog code is highlighted with `minted`:

```
\begin{minted}{prolog}
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A, _, 1, 2),
    predicateWithAtom(someAtom),
    anotherPredicate(B, someAtom, myPredicate(A, _)),
    findall(X, ('testString'(X), myPredicate(A, X)), L1),
    member(A, L1),
    !.
\end{minted}
```

The snippet above produces the following output:

[image: MoreCompleteExample]

As can be seen from this example, atoms are highlighted red, anonymous variables (underscores) are highlighted green, and numbers are grey (or is it cyan?).

Does anyone know how I can customize `listings` the way I want? Keep in mind that I want my listing to be *centered* on the page. (See my other question if you want to know how I make my listing centered.)

Comment: Those Prolog atoms and variables... do they only ever occur within parentheses?

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, they only occur within parentheses. Also I noticed I forget one more thing, a predicate can be inside the parentheses of another predicate. Such as this: `predicate(anotherPredicate(X))`. The `anotherPredicate` is then highlighted just as any other predicate (light blue) and _not_ as an atom.

Comment: Ok. That complicates things. I suggest you edit your answer to cover all those cases. A complete list of specs would be good. Then I or other `listings` lovers will be able to figure out whether implementing such a style in `listings` is feasible.

Comment: @Jubobs All right, I edited my question again. I am pretty sure I got everything covered now.

Comment: In order to properly highlight an identifier as an atom or as a predicate, you would have to look ahead and check whether a `(` is found immediately after the identifier. If a `(` is found, then the identifier is a predicate; otherwise, the identifier is an atom. In theory, you could declare all characters as "letters" in order to allow for such a look-ahead; however, that would seriously upset `listings` and keyword recognition would be, by and large, completely broken. In summary: no, that type of highlighting is not possible with `listings`.

Comment: I think I (mostly) cracked it; have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Months later, after much contorsion, I've managed to put a viable (even if ugly) solution together... thereby [making a liar out of myself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161235/can-the-listings-package-be-set-up-to-highlight-prolog-code-like-minted-does#comment380160_161235) `-_-'`

### Automatic recognition of Prolog predicates, atoms and variables

The solution shown below automatically distinguishes (and highlights in a style very similar to Pygments') Prolog *predicates*, *atoms* and *variables*. No need to manually enter long lists of keywords! In a nutshell, the approach consists in the following:

- Make `listings` treat the opening-parenthesis character as a "letter", in order to test whether that character occurs at the end of identifiers; if it does, then the identifier in question is a *predicate*.
- Otherwise, test the first character of the identifier against `[A-Z_]`; if the test passes, the identifier is a *variable*.
- Otherwise, the identifier is an *atom*.

For a comparison, see the screenshot below.

[image]

### Improvement over Pygments' Prolog lexer

I noticed that Pygments indiscriminately highlights underscores in dark green, and highlights whatever word immediately follows that character as an *atom*... That doesn't make sense to me, because, according to the [Wikipedia page on Prolog syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Data_types), an identifier starting by an underscore is a *variable*, not an *atom*.

The approach shown below improves upon the Pygments Prolog lexer insofar as it highlights underscores differently in different contexts:

- it correctly highlights identifiers starting by an underscore, but composed of at least two characters, as (non-anonymous) Prolog *variables*, and
- it highlights lone underscores, i.e. [Prolog *anonymous variables*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243851/2541573), in a distinct style (dark green).

Correct me if I'm wrong, here; I'm no Prolog expert.

### Missing feature

I didn't bother replicating the highlighting style for numbers; as other questions on the subject attest, that is notoriously difficult, so I'll pass on that, at least for now.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{minted}      % (requires -shell-escape)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% --- ugly internals for language definition ---
%
\makeatletter

% initialisation of user macros
\newcommand\PrologPredicateStyle{}
\newcommand\PrologVarStyle{}
\newcommand\PrologAnonymVarStyle{}
\newcommand\PrologAtomStyle{}
\newcommand\PrologOtherStyle{}
\newcommand\PrologCommentStyle{}

% useful switches (to keep track of context)
\newif\ifpredicate@prolog@
\newif\ifwithinparens@prolog@

% save definition of underscore for test
\lst@SaveOutputDef{`_}\underscore@prolog

% local variables
\newcount\currentchar@prolog

\newcommand\@testChar@prolog%
{%
  % if we're in processing mode...
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \detectTypeAndHighlight@prolog%
  \else
    % ... or within parentheses
    \ifwithinparens@prolog@%
      \detectTypeAndHighlight@prolog%
    \fi
  \fi
  % Some housekeeping...
  \global\predicate@prolog@false%
}

% helper macros
\newcommand\detectTypeAndHighlight@prolog
{%
  % First, assume that we have an atom.
  \def\lst@thestyle{\PrologAtomStyle}%
  % Test whether we have a predicate and modify the style accordingly.
  \ifpredicate@prolog@%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\PrologPredicateStyle}%
  \else
    % Test whether we have a predicate and modify the style accordingly.
    \expandafter\splitfirstchar@prolog\expandafter{\the\lst@token}%
    % Check whether the identifier starts by an underscore.
    \expandafter\ifx\@testChar@prolog\underscore@prolog%
      % Check whether the identifier is '_' (anonymous variable)
      \ifnum\lst@length=1%
        \let\lst@thestyle\PrologAnonymVarStyle%
      \else
        \let\lst@thestyle\PrologVarStyle%
      \fi
    \else
      % Check whether the identifier starts by a capital letter.
      \currentchar@prolog=65
      \loop
        \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter`\@testChar@prolog=\currentchar@prolog%
          \let\lst@thestyle\PrologVarStyle%
          \let\iterate\relax
        \fi
        \advance \currentchar@prolog by 1
        \unless\ifnum\currentchar@prolog>90
      \repeat
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\splitfirstchar@prolog{}
\def\splitfirstchar@prolog#1{\@splitfirstchar@prolog#1\relax}
\newcommand\@splitfirstchar@prolog{}
\def\@splitfirstchar@prolog#1#2\relax{\def\@testChar@prolog{#1}}

% helper macro for () delimiters
\def\beginlstdelim#1#2%
{%
  \def\endlstdelim{\PrologOtherStyle #2\egroup}%
  {\PrologOtherStyle #1}%
  \global\predicate@prolog@false%
  \withinparens@prolog@true%
  \bgroup\aftergroup\endlstdelim%
}

% language name
\newcommand\lang@prolog{Prolog-pretty}
% ``normalised'' language name
\expandafter\lst@NormedDef\expandafter\normlang@prolog%
  \expandafter{\lang@prolog}

% language definition
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lstdefinelanguage\expandafter%
{\lang@prolog}
{%
  language            = Prolog,
  keywords            = {},      % reset all preset keywords
  showstringspaces    = false,
  alsoletter          = (,
  alsoother           = @$,
  moredelim           = **[is][\beginlstdelim{(}{)}]{(}{)},
  MoreSelectCharTable =
    \lst@DefSaveDef{`(}\opparen@prolog{\global\predicate@prolog@true\opparen@prolog},
}

% Hooking into listings to test each ``identifier''
\newcommand\@ddedToOutput@prolog\relax
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\@ddedToOutput@prolog}

\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}
{%
  \ifx\lst@language\normlang@prolog%
    \let\@ddedToOutput@prolog\@testChar@prolog%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{DeInit}{\renewcommand\@ddedToOutput@prolog{}}

\makeatother
%
% --- end of ugly internals ---


% --- definition of a custom style similar to that of Pygments ---
% custom colors
\definecolor{PrologPredicate}{RGB}{000,031,255}
\definecolor{PrologVar}      {RGB}{024,021,125}
\definecolor{PrologAnonymVar}{RGB}{000,127,000}
\definecolor{PrologAtom}     {RGB}{186,032,032}
\definecolor{PrologComment}  {RGB}{063,128,127}
\definecolor{PrologOther}    {RGB}{000,000,000}

% redefinition of user macros for Prolog style
\renewcommand\PrologPredicateStyle{\color{PrologPredicate}}
\renewcommand\PrologVarStyle{\color{PrologVar}}
\renewcommand\PrologAnonymVarStyle{\color{PrologAnonymVar}}
\renewcommand\PrologAtomStyle{\color{PrologAtom}}
\renewcommand\PrologCommentStyle{\itshape\color{PrologComment}}
\renewcommand\PrologOtherStyle{\color{PrologOther}}

% custom style definition 
\lstdefinestyle{Prolog-pygsty}
{
  language     = Prolog-pretty,
  upquote      = true,
  stringstyle  = \PrologAtomStyle,
  commentstyle = \PrologCommentStyle,
  literate     =
    {:-}{{\PrologOtherStyle :-}}2
    {,}{{\PrologOtherStyle ,}}1
    {.}{{\PrologOtherStyle .}}1
}

% global settings
\lstset
{
  captionpos = below,
  frame      = single,
  columns    = fullflexible,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
}

% write some sample code to an external file
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.pl}
somePredicate(_, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A, _variable, 1, 2),
    predicateWithAtom(someAtom),
    anotherPredicate(B, someAtom, myPredicate(A, _)),
    findall(X, ('testString'(X), myPredicate(A, X)), L1),
    member(A, L1),
    !.
    /*
    block comment: blah blah blah
    */
    % to-end-of-line comment: blah blah blah
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section{With \textsf{minted} / Pygments}
%\begin{listing}
%\inputminted[frame=single]{prolog}{sample.pl}
%\caption{Sample Prolog code}
%\end{listing}

\section{With \textsf{Listings}}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{1}
\lstinputlisting[
  style      = Prolog-pygsty,
  caption    = {Using my custom \textsf{listings} style},
]{sample.pl}

\lstinputlisting[
  language = Prolog,
  caption  = {Using \textsf{listings}' default settings for Prolog},
]{sample.pl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but now atoms are not distinguished from variables... any id starting with capital letter is a variable, any id starting with lowercase letter is an atom (a constant), I guess the OP would like to differentiate between them...

Comment: @Bordaigorl Well, I don't know Prolog myself, so I don't know the minutiae. That's why I covered my ass by writing "*on the basis of your code snippet*". The best thing would be a full list of specs and then I could figure out whether mimicking `minted` output is possible.

Comment: Certainly your solution is already very helpful!
Just saying that for presentation, distinguishing between atoms and vars would be very nice.
Moreover, a way to highlight in different ways capitalised and non-cap ids in `listings` would be very helpful in dealing with other languages too!

Comment: @Bordaigorl I posted an answer related to what you're after: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/can-the-listings-package-highlight-by-regexp/159248#159248 I guess I could apply that approach to Prolog identifiers, but I don't have the time at the moment...

Comment: @Jubobs @Bordaigorl Thanks, but yes it would indeed be better if atoms are distinguished from variables. I have just updated my question with an additional example, which (I believe) covers all highlights. I would love to see your answer updated once more, as you are already well on the way to mimic `minted`.

Comment: @Jubobs wow the answer you linked is really impressive! It would be nice if this mechanism could be integrated into the package since it is a quite common thing one might need (think of Haskell, Erlang...)

Comment: Also check Logtalk's syntax coloring support notes for LaTeX at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/coding/latex (Logtalk extends and subsumes Prolog)

Comment: @Bordaigorl My updated answer may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Jubobs very nice indeed! It is also very useful to see how one could hook into `listings` internals to modify its behaviour. I wanted to do something similar for Erlang's syntax `module:call(...)` highlighting module names differently and now I know where to start. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bordaigorl Cool. I'm thinking of teaching myself some Erlang when I get more time. Let me know if you run into trouble with setting up `listings` for it; I might be able to help you out.

Comment: @Jubobs Oh wow that's really great! Thanks for your answer! And about your remark on highlighting variables, it also puzzled me why Pygments highlights a variable starting with an underscore (anonymous variable) as an atom (with the exception for the underscore character itself). So I think your version is better on that part. However, it might be even better if you differentiate variables from anonymous variables, for example with dark green highlights for the entire anonymous variable. Thanks anyway, I didn't expect you would get back to this question. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I think some Prolog users might be interested in such a package. But I doubt that many people will be using it eventually, as Prolog is not that popular.. yet, who knows, maybe your package can become a standard for the Prolog community when they need to document their code.

Comment: @PJvG According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243851/2541573), variables starting by an underscore but whose names consist in more than that underscore are not anonymous variables. Wouldn't it make more sense to highlight only "free-standing" `_` in dark green and to highlight variables such as `_variable` just like any other variable?

Comment: @Jubobs I think that a general option/package/kvinterface for saying to `listings` to assign different styles to capitalised or lower cased tokens would be of interest for many language and many users! Would it be very difficult to generalise your code to set up hooks without specific ref to a language?

Comment: @Jubobs yes, my mistake, you're completely right.

Comment: @Jubobs Very nice!

Comment: I have the issue that closing brackets are added automatically if `breaklines=true` is used. How can this be avoided?