# Why are my custom settings for listings not taken into account?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I would like some help to get my source code to look correct. The code is supposed to look like this:

[image]

As you can see, some words should be purple and bold, some should just be bold, some should be blue and the comments should be green. I'm using the `listings` package for this. See my minimal working example below.

However, for some reason, declaring new keywords using `keywordstyle=[2]{...}` and `keywordstyle=[3]{...}` seems to have no effect. The new keywords are printed like normal text. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{byzantium}{rgb}{0.44, 0.16, 0.39}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\color{mygray},
commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{byzantium},
keywordstyle=[2]\bfseries,
keywordstyle=[3]\color{blue},
morekeywords = {},
keywords=[2]{ePWM_config()},
keywords=[3]{"DSP28x_Project.h",PCLKCR0,bit,TBCLKSYNC},
title=ePWM.c
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
static void ePWM_config()
{
    // Setup Time Base Clock ePWM1
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UPDOWN;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can additional 'keywords' and assign a style (color) to them.

Comment: How do I assign a different style to only particular keywords?

Comment: I know that you can add more keywords by writing "morekeywords={newkeyword}" but not how to set a different style to those keywords.

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: I once used a self written language which derived from `C` and added it somehow as an dialect to the `C` language settings of `listings`, applying other styles to 'my' keywords. I try to find that stuff on my backup disks ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, please do. It would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Jubobs: Why do I get a notice about your comments? Coincidences of names? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I think so. I remember reading somewhere that only writing @<first-name> was sufficient. Here, there's ambiguity :)

Comment: @Jubobs: I should switch my name to klrlsfsdaf, that would prevent such 'errors' ;-) ... ok, this comment is off-topic, I know.

Comment: You should probably replace "look correct" by "look like in eclipse".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least four issues with your `listings` settings.

1. **You load the `C` language too late.** Loading a language discards most of the `listings` tweaks that were performed (using `\lstset`) beforehand. You must load the language *first*, and only then customise the appearance. I recommend you define your own style, for convenience.
2. **You're trying to define things like `"DSP28x_Project.h"` as keywords.** This is awkward because `listings` doesn't allow (by default) `"` in identifiers, and because the `C` language uses `"` as string delimiter. If what you want is to highlight C string literals in blue, you should simply tell `listings` what of your prefered string style is:

   ```
   stringstyle = \color{blue},
   ```
3. **You're trying to define things like `ePWM_config()` as keywords**. By default, `listings` does not allow parentheses to be part of identifiers, for good reason. There are cases where you might want to override that behaviour (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161235/can-the-listings-package-be-set-up-to-highlight-prolog-code-like-minted-does/161237#161237) for an example), but that's unwarranted here. Moreover, parentheses don't seem to be in boldface in your screenshot. Simply define `ePWM_config` (not `ePWM_config()`) as a keyword.
4. **You use a font family that does not come with a boldface typewriter font.** TeX font families, such as Computer Modern (which is used by default in LaTeX), do not provide a boldface typewriter font. When `listings` attempts to typeset stuff in bold typewriter, TeX complains that no such font is available and uses the "normal" (i.e. medium-series) typewriter font instead. To remedy that problem, you must use a font family that comes with boldface typewriter font. A popular choice is Bera Mono. Inserting the following lines in your preamble tells LaTeX to use Bera Mono as typewriter font throughout your LaTeX document.

   ```
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
   ```

**Edit**: if you want the typewriter font to be Bera Mono only in your listings, not in the rest of the document, use something like this:

```
basicstyle = \footnotesize\def\fvm@Scale{.85}\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont
```

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{byzantium}{rgb}{0.44, 0.16, 0.39}

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{myCstyle}{
    language       = C,
    basicstyle     = \footnotesize\def\fvm@Scale{.85}\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont,
    numbers        = left,
    numberstyle    = \color{mygray},
    commentstyle   = \color{mygreen},
    keywordstyle   = \bfseries\color{byzantium},
    keywordstyle   =[2]\bfseries,
    keywordstyle   =[3]\color{blue},
    stringstyle    = \color{blue},
    morekeywords   = {},
    directivestyle = \color{violet}\bfseries,
    morekeywords   =[2]{ePWM_config,ePWM},
    morekeywords   =[3]{PCLKCR0,bit,TBCLKSYNC},
    title          = ePWM.c,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{
\ttfamily
This should be typeset in Computer Modern typewriter font,
contrary to C listings, which should be typeset in scaled-down Bera Mono font.
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myCstyle]
#include  "DSP28x_Project.h"

static void ePWM_config();

#define deadband 76;

void ePWM()
{
    // Stop the Time Base Clock
    EALLOW;
    SysCtrlRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 0;
    EDIS;

    // configure the ePWM
    ePWM_config();

    // Enable the Time Base Clock
    EALLOW;
    SysCtrlRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 1;
    EDIS;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked. However, some of the keywords I have do not work. Such as "DSP28x_Project.h" and adc_isr(). Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @Christian See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way to switch to bera mono just in the code, though? I'm using times new roman in the rest of my thesis and I would prefer to continue doing so.

Comment: Yes, there is. Wait for my next edit.

Comment: Looks absolutely fantastic. Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it! My thesis will look really good thanks to you.