# listings: How can I highlight Makefiles?

Tags: listings, makefile

I am trying to typeset a makefile using `listings`.

Now I would like some differential highlighting, e.g. for variables and ordinary commands in the target body. In this snippet, want to have different highlighting for `VAR` and for `rm -rf`, but it seems the only classes one can style are `identifierstyle`, `stringstyle` and `keywordstyle`. The latter is hardly useful and only highlights builtins (obviously), but `identifierstyle` applies to basically everything, making it utterly useless here.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=[gnu] make}
\lstset{
   language=[gnu] make,
   keywordstyle=\color{teal}\textbf,
   stringstyle=\color{blue},
   identifierstyle=\itshape
}
\begin{lstlisting}
VAR=foo
clean:
   rm -rf $(VAR)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone suggest either an explanation for why this is so (what use is the language definition for `make` if there's no way around it?), or why it should be so, or – preferably – a workaround that does not involve manually specifying e.g. keywords?

**EDIT**: I had some success with `morecomment=[n]{$(}{)}`, but it is crude and prevents actual comment highlighting. Also that does not highlight `VAR` when not surrounded by parentheses. Is there a way to define different classes of comments which can be differentially highlighted?

Comment: The following may be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81646/how-can-i-highlight-text-before-a-character-with-listing/164784#164784