# how to embed arbitrary code

Tags: listings, verbatim

I am using the listings package which does great things for C++, Java.
but what about for a makefile, which isn't one of the supported languages?  I just want the equivalent of listings, nothing fancy, just to embed the text.

I would be happy to include an external makefile, or to paste it in (I'd love to have a choice as in listings).  No special formatting required.  What do I do?  Some kind of verbatim?

Comment: If no special formatting is required, a plain `verbatim` might do.

Comment: The [listings package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) appears to provide support for make. In `lstlang2.sty` you find `\lst@definelanguage[gnu]{make}` and `\lst@definelanguage{make}`.

Comment: Wow, I searched for that (using google) and didn't find it.

Comment: See [listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), Section 2.4 and Table 1.

Comment: @Mike Renfro Why not just post this as an answer? Otherwise I can post my correct code as an answer, but it seems unfair since you found it.

Comment: Technically, @Andrew got there first with a different method. I'm not going to worry about it either way. Either of you can post an answer, the question could be closed, etc.

Comment: Sorry, @andrew, post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [listings package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) has a `make` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}[language=make]
   # I am a comment
   CC=g++
   # CFLAGS options passed to the compiler.
   CFLAGS=-c -Wall

   all: hello

   hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
   $(CC) main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

   clean:
   rm *.o hello
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Having said, this, it doesn't work very well. For example, adding `keywordstyle=\color{red}` to the options list for the `lstlisting` environment should make the keywords red, but it doesn't. (According to `lstlang2.sty`, both `CC` and `CFLAGS` are keywords.)

I had a quick look at the code but I can't see what the problem is. See [How can I highlight text before a character with listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81646/how-can-i-highlight-text-before-a-character-with-listing/164784#164784) for a solution/workaround.